# How to pass user through form

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

views.py

```
def add_phone(request):
    phoneForm = PhoneForm()
    user = request.user
    phone = Phone_info.objects.get(user=2)
    phoneForm = PhoneForm(instance=phone)    
    phone.user=request.user
    if request.method=='POST':        
        phoneForm = PhoneForm(request.POST,request.user,instance=phone) 
        user=request.user       
        if phoneForm.is_valid():
            phone=phoneForm.save(commit=False)
            phone.user=request.user 
            phone.save()
        return redirect('/member/contact-list/')
```

models.py

```
class Phone_info(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    name1 = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class PhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Phone_info
```

In views.py the form.is_valid() is not happening since the user is not pass in form.By what method i can pass the user through form.I am searching the same in google,not getting any idea.Please help me with this.

Comment: Why `user=2` here: `phone = Phone_info.objects.get(user=2)`?

Comment: That is weird: this `phone = Phone_info.objects.get(user=2)` will execute this sql: `SELECT * FROM Phone_info WHERE user_id = 2` so like that you're "hardwiring" the query to user with id=2. I think there what you're trying to do is this: `phone = Phone_info.objects.get(user=request.user)`

Comment: This is ok,i modified no issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do this when you initialize the form:

```
phoneForm = PhoneForm({'user':request.user.id})
```

That way you're passing the user who made the request to the form.

Here's the full method:

```
def add_phone(request):
    user = request.user
    phoneForm = PhoneForm({'user':user.id})
    if request.method=='POST':        
        phoneForm = PhoneForm(request.POST) 
        if phoneForm.is_valid():
            phone=phoneForm.save(commit=False)
            phone.save()
        return redirect('/member/contact-list/')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is giving this error int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'User'

Comment: any form validation to do in forms.py

Comment: only user id is updating,other fields are not saving in db

Comment: But are you passing some input to the form??

Comment: yes sir,what i am thinking is form is looking for user,since i am not passing the user form is not validating

Comment: With this line you are passing the user: `phoneForm = PhoneForm({'user':user.id})` and if you say that is saving only the user to the db then the form is validating and it's saving the Phone am I right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29497/discussion-between-user2086641-and-paulo-bu)

Comment: I am saving data via forms and now i want to show the saved data in forms in editable mode,if i click the link with id,called user name.Can you tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Switching around some should fix your problem

```
def add_phone(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        phoneForm = PhoneForm(request.POST)
        phoneForm.user = request.user #if a phone has a user and a form has a     
        if phoneForm.is_valid():
            phone = phoneForm.save(commit=False)
            phone.save()
        return redirect('/member/contact-list/')
```

I refactored a lot since you have some code that was redundant.
I removed most references to `request.user`

Comment: Sorry, missed a `phone`- updated the code, try again. - Also, could you post your `Form`?